# Can we use begin and end with condition?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a CSV file which has multiple columns. What I am trying to achieve here is to print only the details if column 5<=25. If not then only one single line with string "No certificate will expire in 25 days".

Expectation is to print the column 3 and 6 along with `Error_begin` and `Error_end` string if condition matches.

If not then only need to print date - info - "somestring" in one line only.

Output should be in same log file for both.

Command I am using:

```
awk -F ',' -v date="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" 'BEGIN {if ($5<=25) {print date,"ERROR----"}else { print date,"INFO-- No certificate will expire in 25 days" }} {if ($
5<=25) {print $3,$6}} END {if ($5<=25) {print "ERROR_END"}}' /tmp/cert_details.csv
```

Comment: BEGIN is before reading all data.  END is after.  Data columns are in between. So at begin and end there is no $5

Comment: what is the question? does you code work but you want a 'code review'? does your code not work and you need some ideas on fixes? consider reviewing [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update your question; in particular, provide sample inputs, the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output (corresponding to the sample inputs); in this particular case it looks (to me) like you'll want to provide 2 sets of sample inputs and the 2 sets of expected outputs (ie, demonstrate both sets of logic)

Answer (score 2):

`BEGIN` is executed before processing lines, so accesing any field is equivalent of accessing unset variable, therefore it same as using `0` in numeric comparison, so this piece

```
BEGIN {if ($5<=25) {print date,"ERROR----"}else { print date,"INFO-- No certificate will expire in 25 days" }}
```

will behave like

```
BEGIN {if (0<=25) {print date,"ERROR----"}else { print date,"INFO-- No certificate will expire in 25 days" }}
```

which I suppose is not what you desire.

`END` is executed after all lines and here accessing field pertains to last line that is

```
END {if ($5<=25) {print "ERROR_END"}}
```

is dependant *solely* on last line of your file, which I suppose again is not what you desire.

Note that if you want to make first line of output depend on something which need processing all lines of file, you need to hold print until your line processing do commence, consider simple example, let say you want to print number of lines which have 5 or more character then print said lines and `file.txt` content is

```
Able
Baker
Charlie
```

then possible solution is

```
awk 'length>=5{cnt+=1;lines=lines "\n" $0}END{printf "Found %d lines:%s", cnt, lines}' file.txt
```

output

```
Found 2 lines:
Baker
Charlie
```

Observe that you must not print line as you go, as until reach end you do not know number to be put in first line of output, thus I do store lines of output to be printed, sheared by `\n` (newlines) and do `printf` inside `END`.

*tested in gawk 4.2.1*